# Discrete-time Markov Chains

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

I am having trouble understanding this proof from Markov Chains by Norris (1997)

[image]

How do we get the equality

$P_j(X_n=j \text{ for infinitely many } n ) =P_j(X_n=j \text { for some } n \ge m+1)$
?

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to note that $X_n = j$ for infinitely many $n$ implies $X_n =j$ for some $n \geq m+1$ this gives us

$$P_j(X_n=j \text{ for infinitely many } n ) \leq P_j(X_n=j \text { for some } n \geq m+1) $$

But since

$$1 = P_j(X_n=j \text{ for infinitely many } n ) \leq P_j(X_n=j \text { for some } n \ge m+1) \leq 1 $$

the equality follows